# App crashes when changing into light to dark mode

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, oncreate

In my main activity I'm attaching two fragments and using tablayout. Whenever I change light to dark or dark to light, I'm getting this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94UjU.png)

```
    Process: com.umobi.scantags, PID: 24666
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.umobi.scantags/com.umobi.scantags.activities.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.umobi.scantags.fragments.DeactiveFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
```

and the error is showing in the `onCreate()` of `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` main activity.

Comment: Try to add an empty constructor in your Fragments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unable to instantiate fragment com.umobi.scantags.fragments.DeactiveFragment: could not find Fragment constructor

Your `DeactiveFragment` needs a zero-argument constructor, or alternatively you need to register a `FragmentFactory` that instantiates the fragment without a zero-arg constructor.